# Whats the best way to forma list of objects from different tables using Hibernate and spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a list of objects that contains different types of logs from my db. I would like to build the list such that the order is by most recently made (a date created field that's in each of the tables).

So is the only way to do it by getting each list (4 different kinds of logs) and then cycle through them and put them in the new list by comparing them and getting the most recent one each time? This seems like it could take a long time if the list are really long which they may or may not be.

IS there a better way to do it with Hibernate where I could put all the tables together and have it do the work for me? The tables don't share any keys or anything for a normal join?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

contactLog
has columns (Id, memberId, phonenumber, email, address, dateChanged)

salaryLog
has columns (Id, memberId, salary, dateChanged)

relationsLog
has columns (Id, memberId, relationId, dateChanged)

personalInfoLog
has columns (Id, memberId, height, weight, eyeColor, hairColor, dateChanged)

The purpose of these logs is to indicate anytime someone changes information and Im trying to provide the user with a audit page that will show all changes to these different objects.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using UNION, but if I'm not mistaken, HQL does not support UNION, so you'll have to use native query and result transformer. Here's a sample:

```
     public class Log {
         private Long id;
         private Long memberId;
         private String logType;
         private Date dateChanged;

         // getters & setters here
     }


     public class LogService {

         @PersistenceContext
         private EntityManager em;

         public List<Log> getLogs(){
                final Session sess  = em.unwrap(Session.class);
                final SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(
                    "select id,memberId,'CONTACT' as logType, dateChanged from contactLog"+
                    "union select id,memberId,'SALARY' as logType,dateChanged from salaryLog"+
                    "union select id,memberId,'RELATIONS' as logType,dateChanged from relationsLog"+
                    "union select id,memberId,'PERSONAL INFO' as logType,dateChanged from personalInfoLog "+
                    "order by dateChanged desc";
                );

                query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Log.class));

                return query.list();
         }
     }
```

Notice that only common columns are selected (because you must select the same number of columns from each table when using union).

If you want to view the full details of the log, just use the id to load the specific log and the log type to know from which table you would have to look for the full information.

or

You could modify the query to concat all the changed information into one column for all the tables (which means adding a new field in Log.class).

```
     public class Log {
         private Long id;
         private Long memberId;
         private String logType;
         private Date dateChanged;
         private String changedInfo;
         // getters & setters here
     }
    "select id,memberId,'CONTACT' as logType, dateChanged, phonenumber||','||email||','||address as changedInfo from contactLog"+
                    "union select id,memberId,'SALARY' as logType,dateChanged,salary as changedInfo from salaryLog"+
                    "union select id,memberId,'RELATIONS' as logType,dateChanged,relationId as changedInfo from relationsLog"+
                    "union select id,memberId,'PERSONAL INFO' as logType,dateChanged,  height||','|| weight||','|| eyeColor||','|| hairColor  as changedInfo from personalInfoLog "+
                    "order by dateChanged desc
```

Answer (score 0):

An another approch will be to create a view on your database, and use spring and hibernate as usual.